# Python matplotlib - Color code positive and negative values in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, imshow

I have a bunch of samples with shape (1, 104). All samples are integers(positive, negative and 0) which are being used in the `imshow` function of `matplotlib`. Below is the function I've created to display them as images.

```
def show_as_image(sample):
    bitmap = sample.reshape((13, 8))
    plt.figure()
    # this line needs changes.
    plt.imshow(bitmap, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

I need to **color code** the positive and negative values from the `sample`. **PS: Take 0 as positive.**
How do I change my code?

Comment: What is your question? What does `sample` looks like?

Comment: @harvpan imagine any data frame with [1,104] rows containing positive and negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the normalization of the colorcoding such that it is equally spread between the negative absolute value and positive absolute value of the data. Using a colormap with a light color in the middle can help visualizing how far away from zero the values are.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_as_image(sample):
    bitmap = sample.reshape((13, 8))
    maxval = np.max(np.abs([bitmap.min(),bitmap.max()]))
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(bitmap, cmap='RdYlGn', interpolation='nearest',
               vmin=-maxval, vmax=maxval)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()

sample=np.random.randn(1,104)
show_as_image(sample)
```

[image]

If instead a binary map is required, you may map positive values to e.g. 1 and negative ones to 0.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def show_as_image(sample):
    bitmap = sample.reshape((13, 8))
    bitmap[bitmap >= 0] = 1
    bitmap[bitmap < 0] = 0
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(bitmap, cmap='RdYlGn', interpolation='nearest',
               vmin=-.1, vmax=1.1)
    plt.show()

sample=np.random.randn(1,104)
show_as_image(sample)
```

[image]

In such case the use of a colorbar is probably useless.

Comment: I'm not really interested in knowing how far out my sample values are from max n min. I'm only concerned whether they are +ve or -ve.

Comment: And what if they are `0`?

Comment: then take it as positive. (My bad, I should've mentioned it)

Comment: In that case, in how far is the other answer not exactly what you want?

Comment: Pardon? Are you referring to the other answer written by @Jax?
Yes, that solution will work, ill try it out. I just don't understand the need for a 3-D matrix that he mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a three-dimensional array that assigns a color code to each pixel. So if you want black and white, you will pass `(0,0,0)` and `(1,1,1)`, respectively. Something like this should work:

```
def show_as_image(sample):
    bitmap = sample.reshape((13, 8))
    bitmap_colored = np.zeros((13,8,3))
    bitmap_colored[bitmap>=0] = [1,1,1] # black for values greater or equal to 0
    bitmap_colored[bitmap<0] = [0,0,0] # white for values less than 0
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(bitmap_colored, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
```

For example:

```
>>> sample = np.random.randint(low=-10,high=10,size=(1,104))
>>> show_as_image(sample)
```

will output something like this:
[image]

Comment: That might actually work. Thanks!
Just curious, why do you need a 3-dim matrix? why not 2D or just 1&0?